# Is my Graphics Card dead, or not getting enough Power?

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

Here's my build:

- Gigabyte F2A88XM-D3H FM2/FM2+
- AMD A6-5600K 3.6 GHz Dual-Core <sub>(With Stock Fan)</sub>
- Corsair Vengeance 2x4 8GB DDR3
- 750 Watt Logisys Non-Modular Power Supply (Probably ancient - and overkill),
- and lastly, a single Sapphire HD 6970 2GB GDDR5 Graphics Card, optimized for PCIEx16 2.0

So here's what I know, and have done:

I know that this Graphics Card - and any manuals I find about it - have two power cords going to it (One x6 pin and one x8 pin). However, I neither received a converter unit of any kind for an x8 pin, nor have one for the current power supply.

Power supply is only barely compatible with my setup right now, and it is Self-refurbished.

I have attempted re-seating the Graphics card, and I don't have any other computers that can support this beastly card, let alone power it to test it otherwise. I have tried several HDMI cords and they aren't the issue; I don't have a Display Port plug, a DVI-I cord, nor a monitor/TV to test either on.

I have attempted to force the motherboard to output only to an attached PCI-board, but every time the computer boots up, it has a triple-toned beep, and a single longer beep after it. Normally, the motherboard only beeps once. I can only assume from this "error code" that the motherboard cannot find a unit to transmit to, so I end up resetting the CMOS just to get to the BIOS.

I have **NOT** tried to input another graphics card; I don't have another one readily available.

So, I thought I'd ask before dedicating another fifty dollars to a power supply - is it the graphics card at fault, or the power supply not able to appease both ports? Everything looked to check out otherwise...Right now it's a megafan.

TL/DR: My Graphics Card has two ports for direct power over the PSU - a 6 pin, and an 8 pin, of which only the six pin is plugged in. The Power supply is ancient and barely supports the motherboard. Have tried re-seating the Graphics Card, different cords, and a Motherboard force to pci (resulting in obscure error code), but none worked. I don't have a readily available spare Graphics Card to test. In the end, should I replace my PSU for a better one, or get another Graphics card because this one's DOA?

I don't have Windows assigned to this current computer. It is running Ubuntu x64, a Linux OS. I have Wine installed for windows programs, but most Windows-specific programs may not work.

Comment: First and foremost you should get both of those power connectors connected. With only one connected it is a good bet that the graphics card is not getting enough power and is refusing to start up properly in order to prevent its power regulators from overloading. The best thing to do would be to try the card in another PC with both connectors fitted, but lacking that I would first do whatever was needed to fit both power connectors, they are both needed.

Comment: @Mokubai I am getting a new, better power supply with PCIE 6 and 6x2 support. Will update when it arrives in about a week. I'll keep this in mind, however, and disconnect the graphics card for the time being, since all its doing is hogging useless power.

Comment: You need a 6 and an 8 pin, if your new one has 2 6 pin, make sure you get an adapter so all 8 pins are connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got a new power supply, with 6+2 (or 6x2) support, and it works now. Apologies for being such a noob at computers; this was my first computer build after all.

As a huge facepalm and insult to injury, I took another, more thorough look through the graphics card box, thinking I could ditch the foam and use the box for smaller parts storage -- on the very bottom of the box (for some reason the foam stuck a little), was a two Molex to 8-pin Pci-e connector....imagine my embarrassment.

Thank you for enduring my stupidity. -_-